# I am trying to implement hashing using bucket as a collision resolution technique in php. I am trying to insert the data after hashing into textfile

Tags: php, html, file-handling

in this code, I am creating a hash function and trying to resolve collision using buckets.I have fixed the size of the bucket to 3. I am trying to insert values after hashing into a text file. The insertion is happening but the collision isn't being resolved.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>FOOD DELIVERY</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="insert_item" action="hash_insert.php" method="post">
ID:<input type="text" name="id"><br><br>
Item Name:<input type="text" name="Item_name"><br><br>
Quantity:<input type="text" name="Quantity"><br><br>
Price:<input type="text" name="Price"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])&&isset($_POST['Item_name'])&&isset($_POST['Quantity'])&&isset($_POST['Price'])){
$id=$_POST['id'];
$i_name=$_POST['Item_name'];
$quan=$_POST['Quantity'];
$price=$_POST['Price'];
$file=fopen("Item.txt","a+");

function hash_fun($i){
$t=((($i[3]-48)*100)+(($i[4]-48)*10)+($i[5]-48))%9;
return $t*142;
}

$rec=$id."|".$i_name."|".$quan."|".$price;

while(strlen($rec)<46){
$rec=$rec."_";
}

$pos=hash_fun($id);

fseek($file,$pos,0);
$line=fgets($file);

$cnt=intval($line[0]);

if($cnt==3){
echo "Max collision 3";
}

if($cnt==0){
fseek($file,$pos,0);
fwrite($file,'1');
$pos=$pos+1;
}
else if($cnt==1){
fseek($file,$pos,0);
fwrite($file,'2');
$pos=$pos+48;
}
else if($cnt==2){
fseek($file,$pos,0);
fwrite($file,'3');
$pos=$pos+95;
}
fseek($file,$pos,0);
fwrite($file,$rec);
fwrite($file,"\n");
fclose($file);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

In summary I have into the contexts into a text file called Menu.txt and I am implementing hashing with buckets.But the collision is not being resolved but the insertion is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here:

1. creating a safe hash function is really (REALLY) hard
2. serialization with separators is not safe `$rec=$id."|".$i_name."|".$quan."|".$price`. What if the name contains a pipe char?
3. to avoid race conditions an atomic operation is needed. If two requests are trying to process the same hash more or less at the same time, both requests will succeed. A database will provide mechanisms for that but you can also use the filesystem. For example making directories are atomic operations, if several processes are trying to create one, only one will succeed.
4. sanitize user input. What if the user send line break chars or massive payloads?

In summary, please do not use that code in production for the sake of your users.